# H2Database gives error for SET IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: sql-server, database, h2

I am struggling with this belo error
I use H2Database for unit testing.
I have `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <SchemaName.table_name> ON/OFF;` in our DML .sql file. This works perfectly fine in our production sql server. But this lines fails in h2database.
H2 properties::

```
{
  "driverClass": "org.h2.Driver",
  "user": "test",
  "password": "test",
  "url": "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;IGNORECASE=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=3",
  "properties": {
    "charSet": "UTF-8",
    "mode": "MSSQLServer"
  }
}
```

Error :

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SET IDENTITY_INSERT[*] mytable ON "; expected "@, AUTOCOMMIT, MVCC, EXCLUSIVE, IG
NORECASE, PASSWORD, SALT, MODE, COMPRESS_LOB, DATABASE, COLLATION, BINARY_COLLATION, UUID_COLLATION, CLUSTER, DATABASE_EVENT_LISTENER, ALLOW_LITERALS, DEFA
ULT_TABLE_TYPE, CREATE, HSQLDB.DEFAULT_TABLE_TYPE, PAGE_STORE, CACHE_TYPE, FILE_LOCK, DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT, AUTO_SERVER, AUTO_SERVER_PORT, AUTO_RECONNECT, ASSE
RT, ACCESS_MODE_DATA, OPEN_NEW, JMX, PAGE_SIZE, RECOVER, NAMES, SCOPE_GENERATED_KEYS, SCHEMA, DATESTYLE, SEARCH_PATH, SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH, JAVA_OBJECT_SERIA
LIZER, LOGSIZE, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS"; SQL statement:
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON [42001-199]
```

pom.xml::

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
         <version>1.4.199</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Any help around this is appeciated.

Comment: H2 is not sql server, is it? If so, then you cannot expect to use the same exact syntax.

Comment: H2 does support MODE param where i gave mode as sql server. Issue details gives more info and http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html @SMor